# Checking a status with For loop

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to write a test suite that checks a status in a page. The status appears as text. In order to see any status changes, the page will need to be refreshed first. Usually, the status change occurs within a minute.

So, if done manually, I will have to:

1. Land on a page
2. Check if the status is displayed
3. Check if the displayed status is "Good to go":

   - if it is "Good to go", proceed to any further actions
   - if it is anything else, reload the page until the status is "Good to go"

Two examples that half-worked are:

1. This works well if the status is "Good to go" when I land on the page. If it is not, the page reloads 10 times and if the status becomes "Good to go" in the meantime, it ignores it and keeps reloading the page.

   ```
   ${Status}  Get Text  xpath=//*[@id="status"]
   :FOR    ${CheckStatus}    IN RANGE  10
   \   ${StatusVisible}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Page Should Contain Element  ${Status}
   \   Run Keyword If  '${Status}'=='Good to go'  Exit For Loop  ELSE  Reload Page
   ```
2. This returns this error when I run it:

> Keyword 'BuiltIn.Continue For Loop If' expected 1 argument, got 2

```
    ${Status}  Get Text  xpath=//*[@id="status"]
    :FOR    ${CheckStatus}    IN RANGE  10
    \   ${StatusVisible}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Page Should Contain Element  ${Status}
    \   Continue For Loop If  '${Status}'!=='Good to go'  Reload Page
    \   Exit For Loop If  '${Status}'=='Good to go'
```

I  would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `Run Keyword and Return Status` if you don't even use `${StatusVisible}`?

Comment: I was intending to add a check for its visibility after I solved the issue with the status check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Continue For Loop If` only takes one argument, but you have provided 2.

If it essential that the page be reloaded to check if the status has been changed into the desire one, you can do the following:

```
:FOR    ${CheckStatus}    IN RANGE    10
\    ${Status}    Get Text    xpath=//*[@id="status"]
\    Page Should Contain    ${Status}    # Check that the element exists
\    Exit For Loop If    '${Status}'=='Good to go'    # Break out of loop if status is expected value
\    Run Keyword    Reload Page    # Otherwise, reload and loop again
```

Comment: "Page Should Contain Element" causes an error of element not found. "Page Should Contain" does the trick. However, it causes another issue: if the status changes into the desired one in between reloads, the test fails because it implies the old status should be contained (Page should have contained text 'Wrong status' but did not). Deleting this check entirely makes the test behave like it did on my example #1 (reloads the page 10 times even if the desired status has appeared).

Comment: You can grab the text at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example,keyword 'Continue For Loop If' should contain only one argument. You should remove "Reload Page". That is why you get that error

```
 Continue For Loop If  '${Status}'!=='Good to go'
```

Comment: That does indeed fix that error (I get another one instead). However, if the page is not reloaded, the status cannot be rechecked.

Comment: Let me rephrase: it is trivial to reload the page in order to check if the status has been changed into the desired one.